# Use SAML2 auth with Weblate

Tags: python, django, weblate

I am trying to force [Weblate running in docker](https://github.com/WeblateOrg/docker) to support SAML2 authentication (we have corporate ADFS). I found [plugin for django](https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth). So I create own Dockerfile:

```
from weblate/weblate
RUN set -x \
    && apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y xmlsec1 build-essential \
    && pip install django_saml2_auth

RUN (echo && echo 'execfile("/app/data/settings.override.py")') >> /app/etc/settings.py
```

content of settings.override.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = INSTALLED_APPS + ('django_saml2_auth',)                                                      

SAML2_AUTH = {                                                                                                
    'METADATA_AUTO_CONF_URL': 'https://adfs.homecredit.net/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml',
}
```

I failed with setting of 'urls.py' as mantioned in plugin's manual (I cannot find this file inside docker container) - I am not python/django developer and don't know how to continue.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Weblate already uses python-social-auth, so it's probably easier try it's SAML support first. At least you don't have to care about integration of authentication framework into Weblate, but just on setting up the authentication (what seems to be quite complex thing with SAML anyway).

See their docs for instructions: https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/saml.html

PS: If you manage to setup this, I'm happy to integrate this into Weblate - at least as documentation or any code changes if something is needed.

Comment: Thanks for hint. Looks easier than my previous path, but still not easy. Firstly there is missing `python-saml` library in docker image. See [commit](https://github.com/martinberanek/weblate-docker/commit/0d9f0305537c9a8705a6d1c2998708c326c6b434) for more info. And also there is problem generate own metadata as described at [documentation](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/saml.html#basic-usage)

Comment: Indeed, it's not (yet) integrated. I've added needed library in https://github.com/WeblateOrg/docker/commit/479284bb62a32478b2576a9537845dc119d59b8c. The generating XML configuration looks a bit ugly this way, I'm not sure if it can be integrated somehow better...

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to integrate this app into my dev environment, and I got stuck on a different issue, you can see in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50162705/django-saml-integration)

Regarding your question- why are you creating `settings.override.py`? 
Do you not have access to modify `settings.py`? 
You need to see where the file actually resides in the Docker environment, did you place it in the wrong location? 
It might be that you need to `ADD` the file, i.e:

```
ADD <file_name> /you/path/here/<file_name>
```

And then `RUN` the `exec` on that file.